# VB6 Application ODBC Error

Tags: vba, vb6

I have a VB6 application working with.
This application uses ODBC to access a Microsoft Access database.
I am sure that the database string is correct as the database contains the information used to login and the login works just fine. I also have the same string at every instance.

However, at a certain point the ODBC driver error-"Data source name not found and no default driver specified" appears...The issue is:

This occurs whenever I press a specific button. This button opens a form:

```
Private sub Munubttn_Click()
frmLog.Show
End Sub
```

However, in the form frmLog, I placed a message box as the first command under the Form_Load() sub. Now whenever the button is clicked, I get the error, just before the message box. As such, I do not know where this error originates. So I suppose the question is, what code does the form execute just before it loads? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. VB6 is not the same as VB.NET. 2. You do not show us the code in the Form_Load event so we will probably not be able to help you. Possible help: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/306345

Comment: Put a break point on frmLog.Show. Click the button and the program will stop on the frmLog.Show line BEFORE it runs the code. Then use F8 to step through the code.

Comment: So your database calls work fine in other places/forms, it is just the one form that errors?

Answer (score -1):

> So I suppose the question is, what code does the form execute just before it loads?

The only code that would be executed would be the class initialize sub.  Given your described scenario, the problematic logic is likely in a [`Class_Initialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fxtxxwa%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) sub within the `frmLog` Form.